# Grabbing text from a list with no ID or class using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I don't understand why the list I'm trying to extract the text from is returning blanks when I'm definitely using the correct `Xpath`. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.omegawatches.com/watch-omega-specialities-first-omega-wrist-chronograph-51652483004001")
betweenLugs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/main/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]")])
print(betweenLugs.text)
```

This should grab the first list item and measurement

```
Between lugs: 20 mm
```

I have also tried other methods, but the fact that `Xpath` doesn't pick it up tells me something is wrong and it doesn't matter how I do it, I won't be able to extract the text inside the lists. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? This is the first time I've ran into this problem.

Comment: I think the line should be: betweenLugs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/main/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/li")])[0]

Comment: Every list item within the unordered list in regards to the technical information, so that would be everything from "Between Lugs" all the way down to "Water Resistant" and all the appropriate values that pertain to the headings.

Comment: @Alichino that unfortunately just prints blank; no error or content. I was having that issue as well when trying different things. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, try this and see if it solves the problem:

```
between_lugs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Between lugs')]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
between_lugs_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Between lugs')]/../span").get_attribute("innerHTML")

final_text = between_lugs + " " + between_lugs_value
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this returns: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(text(), 'Between lugs')]"

Comment: It works for me in the python interpreter... Please copy the URL you are on again :)

Comment: I see, I think it's because my browser automatically takes it to the German site. The link I gave was to the US so that's probably why. My fault. The URL is here: https://www.omegawatches.com/de/watch-omega-specialities-first-omega-wrist-chronograph-51652483004001 but I think if I just change a few things accordingly it should work.

Comment: I think it should :) Or change the text in CONTAINS to "Zwischen den Bandanstößen" :D PS. Also, the value has a space after the number in the form of &nbsp;  -- you can do between_lugs_value = between_lugs_value.replace("&nbsp;"," ")

Comment: Yep, this gets it pretty much how I need it, just need to strip a few things away but otherwise looks good. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `xpath` is wrong. It fails in `/div[2]`, it doesn't match anything. This is an example why you shouldn't use absolute path.

The section has `id` attribute, use it

```
betweenLugs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='product-info-data-5bea7fa7406d7']/ul/li[1]")[0]
```

You might also want to add some wait for the loading

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

betweenLugs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='product-info-data-5bea7fa7406d7']/ul/li[1]")))
```

Comment: That's a better idea, I will try and use your suggestion, however when indexing with [0], I get the error "list index is out of range."

Comment: @LRBrady It might be timing issue, I updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the edit, I'm not sure it's a timing issue because even with the edit, selenium is just timing out and not finding anything. I'll continue with your suggestion and try to make some changes.

Comment: It seems that the last bit of the ID (something like 5bea7[...]) is dynamically generated? I don't think it's reliable.

Comment: @Alichino I noticed that, but after closing the page and reopening it it remained the same.

Comment: @LRBrady The section is not visible before scrolling, there is some html rendering. `visibility_of_element_located` might not work, try `presence_of_element_located` instead.

Comment: @Guy Unfortunately not, maybe I should tell Selenium to scroll down slightly before searching and that will work.

Comment: @LRBrady Try to maximize the window `driver.maximize_window()`, call it after the driver initialization.

Comment: @Guy It still seems to time out with that, this text is tricky to get a hold of but I think the other answer has given the best results. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

That page already has jQuery on it so you can just:

```
driver.execute_script("return jQuery('li:contains(Between lugs)').text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')")
```

You can fiddle with selectors in the chrome selectors, it makes it much easier.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler approach might be the following one:

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

url = "https://www.omegawatches.com/watch-omega-specialities-first-omega-wrist-chronograph-51652483004001"

with closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as wd:
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    wd.get(url)
    item = wait.until(lambda wd: wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'technical-data')]//li")).get_attribute('textContent')
    print(' '.join(item.split()))
```

Output:

```
Between lugs: 20 mm
```

Comment: I find it very handy when It comes to open and quit the browser in a single shot @QHarr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a scroll down and a wait with a css selector to target the parent li

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.omegawatches.com/watch-omega-specialities-first-omega-wrist-chronograph-51652483004001")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2000)") 
betweenLugs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#product-info-data-5beaf5497d916 > ul > li:nth-child(1)")))

print(betweenLugs.text)
```